# Numpy for loop gives a different result each time

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, pandas

First time publishing in here, here it goes:

I have two sets of data(v and t), each one has 46 values. The data is imported with "pandas" module and coverted to a numpy array in order to do the calculation.

I need to set ml_min1[45], ml_min2[45], and so on to the value "0". The problem is that each time I ran the script, **the values corresponding to the position 45 of ml_min1 and ml_min2 are different**. This is the piece of code that I have:

```
t1 = fil_copy.t1.as_matrix()
t2 = fil_copy.t2.as_matrix()
v1 = fil_copy.v1.as_matrix()
v2 = fil_copy.v2.as_matrix()

ml_min1 = np.empty(len(t1))
l_h1 = np.empty(len(t1))

ml_min2 = np.empty(len(t2))
l_h2 = np.empty(len(t2))

for i in range(0, (len(v1) - 1)):

    if (i != (len(v1) - 1)) and (v1[i+1] > v1[i]):
        ml_min1[i] = v1[i+1] - v1[i]
        l_h1[i] = ml_min1[i] * (60/1000)
    elif i == (len(v1)-1):
        ml_min1[i] = 0
        l_h1[i] = 0
        print(i, ml_min1[i])
    else:
        ml_min1[i] = 0
        l_h1[i] = 0
        print(i, ml_min1[i])

for i in range(0, (len(v2) - 1)):

    if (i != (len(v2) - 1)) and (v2[i+1] > v2[i]):
        ml_min2[i] = v2[i+1] - v2[i]
        l_h2[i] = ml_min2[i] * (60/1000)
    elif i == (len(v2)-1):
        ml_min2[i] = 0
        l_h2[i] = 0
        print(i, ml_min2[i])
    else:
        ml_min2[i] = 0
        l_h2[i] = 0
        print(i, ml_min2[i])
```

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but `i` will never equal `len(v1) - 1`, so neither `elif` will ever fire. Also, range(0, x) == range(x).

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to loop over the range 0 ≤ i < len(v1). If so, you should have just said `range(len(v1))`. But since you treat the last `i` differently, you could in fact use `range(len(v1) - 1)` and move the `elif` body to after the for-loop (use `-1` as the index instead of `i`).

Comment: *"I need to set v1[45], v2[45] to the value "0""* - at no point in this code are you modifying any element of either `v1` or `v2`

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos there is a  point, where I do the calculation `v1[i+1] - v1[i]`, so when i = 45,  v1[i+1]  = v1[46] , which doesn't exist. And I think, this is the problem, so I did the elif statement:  `elif i == (len(v2)-1` ; in order to establish the i-postion 45 -value to zero.

Comment: @ali_m My mistake, I meant `ml_min1`, `l_h1`,...and so on.

Comment: also, in the first for, in the elif, it should be printing `print(i, ml_min1[i])`

Comment: you're right @GabrielIlharco

Comment: @MatS I don't know how to restate, “`i` will never equal `len(v1) - 1`” (ditto for `v2` in the second loop) any more clearly.

Comment: Thanks @MarceloCantos, I get it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it is currently written doesn't work because the `elif` blocks are never hit, since `range(0, x)` does not include `x` (it stops just before getting there). The easiest way to solve this is probably just to initialize your output arrays with `numpy.zeros` rather than `numpy.empty`, since then you don't need to do anything in the `elif` and `else` blocks (you can just delete them).

That said, it's generally a design error to use loops like yours in numpy code. Instead, you should use numpy's broadcasting features to perform your mathematical operations to a whole array (or a slice of one) at once.

If I understand correctly, the following should be equivalent to what you wanted your code to do (just for one of the arrays, the other should work the same):

```
ml_min1 = np.zeros(len(t1)) # use zeros rather than empty, so we don't need to assign any 0s
diff = v1[1:] - v1[:-1]     # find the differences between all adjacent values (using slices)
mask = diff > 0             # check which ones are positive (creates a Boolean array)
ml_min1[:-1][mask] = diff[mask]   # assign with mask to a slice of the ml_min1 array
l_h1 = ml_min1 * (60/1000)  # create l_h1 array with a broadcast scalar multiplication
```

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght !!! I didn't  have even considered this option, I should learn more about numpy. Your solution with "broadcasting" is way more elegant, time saving, and easy to understand.